# How to set cursor speed on login screen with xserver-xorg-input-libinput?

Tags: gnome, xorg, login, configuration, cursor

Since installing the `xserver-xorg-input-libinput` package I have been able to set my cursor speed on Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 with GNOME 3.20, and I have it at a speed I like, whereas the default was too fast for me.

However there is one problem, the default speed is still in use on the login screen. This is most likely because I have set it for my account, but on the login screen I am not yet logged in so it just has the default.

So how can I change the cursor speed on the login screen?